# How fix Ubuntu after execute sudo apt-get install -f

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

First off all, sorry for my English.

Probably after executing this command :

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I uninstalled most apps from my system. After login I see only wallpaper, top and bottom toolbar disappeared.
I have Ubuntu 12.04
Please Help

Comment: [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"sudo apt-get install -f" only fixes missing dependancies, it is probably not what is causing your problem.

You might want to reinstall your UI.

Comment: install ubuntu-desktop helped  thank u so much ;)